# Fine-tuned Stable Diffusion not converging with custom encoder

Tags: image-generation, embeddings, diffusion-models

I'm currently fine-tuning a stable diffusion model for the task of dataset augmentation. I am training the model on 80k images from hte CelebA-attributes dataset, replacing the text encoder with learnt embedding layers that encode the binary attribute vectors. I've trained a model, which generates images that look generally like faces, however, many of them are hit-or-miss, being low quality, and unrealistic. During training, the average loss from MSE loss of 0.18 in the first epoch down to 0.155, then stays there for the rest of training; I'm not sure what a good "loss trajectory" would look like for diffusion models, and if I should try something else.

My main concerns are as follows:

- Is my method of encoding the "prompts" (the binary attribute vectors) valid? Is my setup adequate so they can be optimized?
- What would a good loss function trajectory be for this sort of model?
- What hyperparameters could lead to better results?

Below is some code to show my setup. Keep in mind, although I use the term "prompt", it doesn't refer to text, but rather, a list of binary attributes that are used to condition the model to generate faces with certain qualities (i.e blonde, male, beard etc). A prompt would look like this:

```
[-1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1]
```

My models:

```
class CombinedModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, unet, prompt_encoder):
        super(CombinedModel, self).__init__()
        self.unet = unet
        self.prompt_encoder = prompt_encoder

    def forward(self, pixel_values, attributes, timesteps, ignore_prompt_embedding=False):
        # First, get the embedded attributes
        embedded_attributes = self.prompt_encoder(attributes, ignore_prompt_embedding=ignore_prompt_embedding)

        # Now, pass the necessary inputs along with the embedded attributes to the U-Net
        output = self.unet(pixel_values, timesteps, encoder_hidden_states=embedded_attributes, return_dict=False)[0]

        return output

class AttributeEmbeddingModel(ModelMixin, ConfigMixin):
    @register_to_config
    def __init__(self, num_attributes, embedding_size, intermediate_size):
        super(AttributeEmbeddingModel, self).__init__()
        #assuming binary attributes, so num_embeddings is 2
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(num_embeddings=2, embedding_dim=embedding_size)
        self.num_attributes = num_attributes
        # Assuming intermediate_size is the target output size
        # Adjust the linear layer accordingly
        self.intermediate_layer = nn.Linear(embedding_size * num_attributes, intermediate_size)
        self.activation = nn.ReLU()

    def forward(self, attributes, ignore_prompt_embedding=False):
        if ignore_prompt_embedding:
            # Adjust the shape to [batch_size, 1, num_attributes] and convert to float
            resized_attributes = attributes.unsqueeze(1).float()  # Convert to float
            return resized_attributes
        batch_size = attributes.shape[0]

        indices = (attributes + 1) // 2
        embedded_attributes = self.embedding(indices)
        # Flatten the embeddings to combine them before the intermediate layer
        embedded_attributes = embedded_attributes.view(batch_size, -1)
        intermediate_output = self.intermediate_layer(embedded_attributes)
        activated_output = self.activation(intermediate_output)
        # No need to reshape if you want the output to be [batch_size, intermediate_size]
        return activated_output.unsqueeze(1)
```

My training loop:

```
        for step, batch in enumerate(train_dataloader):
            num_steps +=1

            # Use the accelerator context manager for the unet model
            with accelerator.accumulate(unet_prompt_model):
                # NOTE: batch["pixel_values"] is a list of tensors, one for each image in the batch
                # NOTE: batch["prompt"] is a list of tensors, one for each attribute row in the batch

                # Convert images to latent space
                latents = vae.encode(batch["pixel_values"].to(weight_dtype)).latent_dist.sample()
                latents = latents * vae.config.scaling_factor

                # Sample noise that we'll add to the latents
                noise = torch.randn_like(latents)
                bsz = latents.shape[0]
                # Sample a random timestep for each image
                timesteps = torch.randint(0, noise_scheduler.config.num_train_timesteps, (bsz,), device=latents.device)
                timesteps = timesteps.long()

                noisy_latents = noise_scheduler.add_noise(latents, noise, timesteps)
                noisy_latents.requires_grad_(True) #TODO fix this

                # Target:
                target = noise
                # target can be v_prediction too:
                # target = noise_scheduler.get_velocity(latents, noise, timesteps)

                # Encode the prompt.
                attributes = batch["prompt"].to(accelerator.device)  # Directly move to device without stacking
                model_pred = unet_prompt_model(
                    noisy_latents,
                    attributes,
                    timesteps,
                    ignore_prompt_embedding=ignore_prompt_embedding
                )

                #  maybe snr loss here instead of mse
                loss = F.mse_loss(model_pred.float(), target.float(), reduction="mean")

                # Gather the losses across all processes for logging (if we use distributed training).
                avg_loss = accelerator.gather(loss.repeat(conf.train_batch_size)).mean()
                train_loss += avg_loss.item() / conf.gradient_accumulation_steps
                loss_this_epoch += avg_loss.item()

                # Backpropagate
                accelerator.backward(loss)
                if accelerator.sync_gradients:
                    accelerator.clip_grad_norm_(unet_prompt_model.parameters(), 1.0)
                optimizer.step()
                lr_scheduler.step()
                optimizer.zero_grad()
```

And finally, my current hyperparams:

````
@dataclass
class TrainingConfig80k:
    # This model is 128x128, which is what we're aiming for
    pretrained_hf_model = "bguisard/stable-diffusion-nano-2-1"

    # the generated image resolution
    image_size = 128
    train_batch_size = 256
    dataloader_num_workers = 2
    gradient_accumulation_steps = 1

    num_epochs = 50
    learning_rate = 1e-6
    lr_warmup_steps = 200
    use_ema = 0 # do not use ema, didn't seem to help

    num_inference_steps = 50

    save_image_epochs = 2
    save_model_epochs = 5
    max_checkpoints_saved=5

    mixed_precision = 'fp16'  # `no` for float32, `fp16` for automatic mixed precision
    output_dir = 'LDA-CelebA-128-80k'  # the model namy locally and on the HF Hub

    dataset_hf_dir = "tpremoli/CelebA-attrs-80k"

    hf_repo_id="tpremoli/LDA-CelebA-128-80k"

    # Choose between
    # ["linear", "cosine", "cosine_with_restarts", "polynomial", "constant", "constant_with_warmup"]'
    lr_scheduler="cosine_with_restarts"

    prompt_embedding_first_size = 256
    prompt_embedding_final_size = 128
    ignore_prompt_embedding = False

    seed = None

    train_transforms = transforms.Compose(
        [
            transforms.Resize(image_size, interpolation=transforms.InterpolationMode.BILINEAR),
            transforms.CenterCrop(image_size),
            transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
            transforms.ToTensor(),
            transforms.Normalize([0.5], [0.5]),
        ]
    )

    def preprocess_train(self, examples):
        images = [image.convert("RGB") for image in examples["image"]]
        examples["pixel_values"] = [self.train_transforms(image) for image in images]
        examples["prompt_str"] = [ps for ps in examples["prompt_string"]]
        examples["prompt"] = tokenize_attributes_to_tensor_list(examples)
        return examples
```
````